# How to segment an string/array in <optgroup> and <option> divided by a specific character?

Tags: javascript, html, optgroup

I need to divide my array into groups and options in a `<select>`. I don't know how to do it dynamically, since my array contains strings divided by `:`, which means it can have the same groups with options and groups with groups inside it.

My actual problem is how to get the groups and options by the string.

I have an array that's returning this specific data:

```
const data = [
    { id: 1, raw_name: "vehicle:car:ford"},
    { id: 2, raw_name: "vehicle:motorbike:honda"},
    { id: 3, raw_name: "none"},
    { id: 4, raw_name: "vehicle:car:fiat"},
    { id: 5, raw_name: "vehicle:car:bmw"},
    { id: 6, raw_name: "vehicle:motorbike:suzuki"},
    { id: 7, raw_name: "vehicle:plane:jets:gulfstream"},
    { id: 8, raw_name: "vehicle:bike"}
  ];
```

I've tried to split `raw_name` by `:` and do a for loop to create the group and the options with the result, but unfortunately it does not organize by itself.

My code:

```
<select id="bankselect">

</select>

<script>
    const select = document.getElementById("bankselect");
    let optGroup;
    data.forEach((element => {
        for (let index = 0; index < element.opt.length; index++) {
            if (index + 1 === element.opt.length) {
                const opt = document.createElement("option");
                opt.value = element.opt[index];
                opt.innerText = element.opt[index];
                optGroup.append(opt);
            } else {
                optGroup = document.createElement("optgroup");
                optGroup.label = element.opt[index];
            }
            select.append(optGroup);
        }
    }))
</script>
```

My result:

[image]

My expected final outcome would be this:

```
<select id="bankselect">
    <option>none</option>
    <optgroup label="vehicle">
      <option>bike</option>
      <optgroup label="car">
        <option>ford</option>
        <option>fiat</option>
        <option>bmw</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="motorbike">
        <option>honda</option>
        <option>suzuki</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="plane">
        <optgroup label="jets">
          <option>gulfstream</option>
         </optgroup>
      </optgroup>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
```

[image]

Comment: Note that optgroup elements may _not_ contain other optgroup elements, they may only contain option elements (See the "permitted content" description over on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup)). So what you're seeing is correct: you get the `plane` optgroup, but if you then try to nest `jets` under that, the browser notices illegal nesting taking place, and resolves that by finding the nearest legal spot for that `append`, making it a sibling instead of a child.

Comment: Try splitting the values, separated by `:`, into an array. To do this, you can use the `split` method. Here is an example, that will print in the console the array created from the string provided that is being splitted: `console.log("vehicle:car:ford".split(":"))`. Let me know if made your life easier or not.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans this is not a problem, I'm using a framework! I'm looking a way to get them in a specific group.

Comment: @acarlstein I did, I splited it and tried to put in groups and options, look my answer now!

Comment: For some reason, I can't see your answer below the question. Did the suggestion works for you?

Comment: @beletate then first do that: convert your flat data to grouped data and then work with that instead (see answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, turn that flat data into nested data, and then use the nested data to recursively build your `<select>` content:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, raw_name: "vehicle:car:ford"},
  { id: 2, raw_name: "vehicle:motorbike:honda"},
  { id: 3, raw_name: "none"},
  { id: 4, raw_name: "vehicle:car:fiat"},
  { id: 5, raw_name: "vehicle:car:bmw"},
  { id: 6, raw_name: "vehicle:motorbike:suzuki"},
  { id: 7, raw_name: "vehicle:plane:jets:gulfstream"},
  { id: 8, raw_name: "vehicle:bike"}
];

// First, give that data a sensible ordering
data.sort((a,b) => a.raw_name < b.raw_name ? -1 : 1);

// Then convert it to a tree form
const nested = convertFlatToNested(data);

// And then convert that tree to a <select>
const select = createPulldownMenu(nested);

// And put that <select> on the page
document.body.appendChild(select);

/**
 * Convert the flat data to a nested tree form,
 * by splitting the name on : and inserting the
 * resulting "path" as an object property chain.
 */
function convertFlatToNested(data) {
  const top = {};
  data.forEach(({ id, raw_name })=> {
    let level = top, term, terms = raw_name.split(`:`);
    while (terms.length) {
      term = terms.shift();
      level[term] ??= {};
      level = level[term];
    }
  });
  return top;
}

/**
 * Create a select element, and fill it with options.
 */
function createPulldownMenu(data) {
  const select = document.createElement(`select`);
  return addOptions(select, data);
}

/**
 * Take a nested data object, and convert any
 * key that maps to an empty object to an <option>,
 * and any key that maps to an object with values
 * to an <optgroup>, then recursively filling that
 * optgroup.
 */
function addOptions(parent, data) {
  Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (Object.keys(value).length === 0) {
      const child = document.createElement(`option`);
      child.name = child.value = child.textContent = key;
      parent.appendChild(child);
    } else {
      const child = document.createElement(`optgroup`);
      child.label = key;
      parent.appendChild(child);
      addOptions(child, value);
    }
  });
  return parent;
}
```

This ends up generating the following (*bad*!) nesting:

```html
<select>
  <option value="none">none</option>
  <optgroup label="vehicle">
    <option value="bike">bike</option>
    <optgroup label="car">
      <option value="bmw">bmw</option>
      <option value="fiat">fiat</option>
      <option value="ford">ford</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="motorbike">
      <option value="honda">honda</option>
      <option value="suzuki">suzuki</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="plane">
      <optgroup label="jets">
        <option value="gulfstream">gulfstream</option>
      </optgroup>
    </optgroup>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Because bear in mind: you can't nest `<optgroup>` elements. That is to say, you "can", but it's invalid HTML and while browsers will do something reasonably sensible with that invalid HTML, it's still *invalid HTML* and you should reconsider how to show this data, because you're basically using the wrong UI element for this data.

Comment: Mike, tks a lot! It was exactly what I wanted, but as you said, its a invalid HTML and I couldn't use! But I really appreciate your help!

Comment: A more typical approach if you have (deeply) nested ontologies is to generate multiple selects to allow folks to filter the category down to the most specific one, and then present the options in that one hyper-specific category.